# What is the effect of an acidic solution on hydrolytic enzymes?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, ecology, enzymes, mycology

I'm working on a school research project and my research question is "What is the effect of increasing concentrations of Acid X on hydrolytic enzymes, measured through the loss of mass of leaf litter after 30 minutes?"

Note that the acid to be used will be chosen later and the time of the reaction can be altered. I plan to use at least one of these hydrolytic enzymes: endoglucanase, cellobiohydrolase, and β-Glucosidase.

I have spent days on end searching for information on hydrolytic enzymes and acids (their relationship). I have been unable to find anything. Do hydrolytic enzymes follow the normal trend of denaturation under a change in pH?

Comment: There is a good amount of information about this online, I was able to find information in one google search, for example https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4875970/

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Not all enzymes behave the same way so, in addition to being under-researched, this is also too broad. Thank you for taking the tour, but please also consult the [help] staring with [ask] effectively on this site, [what is on-topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and [what is not](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). You should also search for and read the "homework" policy for this site. Thanks.